# Google Sheets - Send email based on another cell's text

Tags: email, text, google-sheets, cell, send

I have a script that sends an email for every cell within a range of cells. To prevent sending duplicate emails whenever the script is re-run, it marks a cell (column C) in each row every time an email is sent. Please see the example in ‘Sheet2’.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_oMbZZjOhfdKuYNWOuyF3fao8yO6W3juFjUsFbFBJaU/edit?usp=sharing

However, I want to convert this into a script for 'Sheet1' that sends an email whenever a cell within its corresponding row contains specific text. In this example, whenever column I contains a checkmark (✓), I would like for a message (column E) to be sent with its corresponding subject line (column D). I also want to prevent duplicate emails, much like the example in ’Sheet2’. In other words, once column I contains a checkmark, the message is sent, completed, and will not re-send unless the checkmark is deleted and re-entered.

```js
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "ta.ri...@gmail.com"; 
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[0];   // First column
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      s.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "ta.ri...@gmail.com"; 
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (row[8]) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[0];   // First column
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      s.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue("");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper, thank you for the help! I'm sorry but I'm pretty new to google scripting and I'm not sure how to get this to work with Sheet1. When selecting the checkmark I don't receive anything in my inbox. I changed a couple of things: var startRow = 3 and var dataRange = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3 because in Sheet 1 the rows are different -- still nothing. I'm aiming for an email to send as soon as I click the checkmark on the dropdown menu. Also, rather than sending emails from a range of cells, I'd like to only send an email if it's row contains a checkmark.